# Selenium Web Driver multiple windows

Tags: java, selenium

Scenario is 
IN gmail email popup out if i am clicking on send button Email will send that popup will close automatically once i click on send button

My question is
if child window close automatically after how to switch to parent window?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by getting a handle to the parent window before you switch to the new window. Then after the new window closes you can switch back to the parent using this handle.

```
// before opening the new window
String parentWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

// after closing the new window
driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandle);
```